# How to seek youtube video on youtube.com?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

How to interact with the YouTube player on youtube.com – not the iFrame API? E.g. seek or play/pause the video. I want to set current time of playing video programmatically with my extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//First get the video

var myPlayer = document.getElementsByClassName('video-stream html5-main-video')[0];


//Now you can:

//Play video with
myPlayer.play()

//Pause video with
myPlayer.pause()

//Go to particular time with
myPlayer.currentTime = 40
//will take your video to 40 seconds.

//To get current time just use 
myPlayer.currentTime
```